# override Image.phtml or Image_with_border.phtml in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

i 've had a requirement in whch i have to make module to show labels on the products images on listing page. i can do that by overriding **list.phtml** file in **catalog_category_view.xml** but i want to do that by overriding **image.phtml** so that wherever the **getImage()** method will be called set to show html it will show the labels? can anyone tell me that how can i do that? and please do tell me that is it a good practice or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the image_with_borders.phtml by copying the original file to

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml

However, be aware that by doing these, all images rendered by lists or widgets will be affected.